# Can you use MAAS without PXE or WOL?

Tags: maas

I am trying to evaluate MAAS using one laptop to install another. The target
laptop does not have Wake on Lan, and doesn't seem to have any of the other power types
listed in the selection dialog box either.

Is it possible to use MAAS by manually switching on & rebooting the target machine?

I am using MAAS on 14.04, and I am trying to install the same release.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I encountered the same problem when trying to evaluate MAAS using virtual machines (because VirtualBox doesn't support WOL). But yes, you can just turn them on when the controller sends the WOL signal, it won't make any difference as long as it turns on within a reasonable amount of time from when the WOL signal was sent